# Partial Array Error

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, syntax-error

My professor gave this example in class and it worked perfectly for him, but when I copied it down and tried to run it myself, I'm getting a number of errors.

i.e expandArray() in the type classExample is not appplicable for the arguments(int, int)

i.e for expandArray() : insert "...VariableDeclarartorId" to complete FormalParameterList

i.e. Syntax errors on "}" tokens.

I think it has to do with the placement of the class PartArray, because he seemed to have it in the classExample, but my TA just told me that you can't declare a class within another class. Did I make a mistake copying it down?

```
public class classExample{

public static int INITIAL_SIZE = 100; 


public static void main(String[] args) { 

PartArray part = new PartArray();//object

part.array = new String[INITIAL_SIZE];//field

part.array[part.size++] = "Bob";
part.array[part.size++] = "Percy";

expandArray(part.size, 2*INITIAL_SIZE);

System.out.println(part);
System.out.println("part.size: " + part.size);
System.out.println("part.array.length: " + part.array.length);
System.out.println("part.array[0]: " + part.array[0]);
System.out.println("part.array[1]: " + part.array[1]);
System.out.println("part.array[2]: " + part.array[2]);

}//main


public static void expandArray(PartArray.full, int newSize){
String[] newArray = new String[newSize];

for(int pos = 0; pos < full.array.length; pos ++) //every position in fullArray
{newArray[pos] = full.array[pos];
}//for

full.array = newArray; //match object

return;

}//expandArray

}//classExample

class PartArray { //local container to hold partially filled array
public int INITIAL_SIZE = 100;
public int size = 0; //number of entries in array
public String[] array = new String[INITIAL_SIZE];//storage location
}
```

Comment: `public static void expandArray(PartArray full, int newSize)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This,

```
public static void expandArray(PartArray.full, int newSize){
```

should be

```
public static void expandArray(PartArray full, int newSize){
```

And, I think this

```
expandArray(part.size, 2*INITIAL_SIZE);
```

should be

```
expandArray(part, 2*INITIAL_SIZE);
```

Comment: You are right! Thank-you! So, to clarify - we should always call the whole object in a method?

Comment: @hello **no**. Your error told you that `PartArray.full` was *insert "...VariableDeclarartorId" to complete FormalParameterList* and the second change is necessary because *expandArray() in the type classExample is not appplicable for the arguments(int, int)*